# How to get an element range in linq within a sequence?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this query to collection:

```
Panel thePanel = menuCell.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
                    .Where(panel => panel.Controls.OfType<HyperLink>().Any(
                        label => label.ID == clas))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This gets only the Panel that has an hyperlink with a certain id. I need to get not only the `firstOrDefault` but **the matched element (only the first) and the 2 next** within the sequence. I didn't try anything because don't know how.

Comment: The question is unclear. Terms such as "first", "next two" imply any order. IEnumearble(Of T) is not ordered sequence. Then, when we operating with terms such above, we must set the ordering condition exactly.

Comment: `First`, is the matched element, 2 next are the 2 next in the sequence that follow the matched one.

Comment: Matched element can be more than 1, and next 2 can be any of 2 if there are no exact order.

Comment: No, there will be only one matched element.

Comment: next two means, proceed a simple iteration start from the matched element. "IEnumerable xposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection."

Comment: OK. But next 2 can be any 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will return first three panels, which have hyperlinks with a certain id

```
var thePanels = menuCell.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
                    .Where(panel => panel.Controls.OfType<HyperLink>()
                                         .Any(label => label.ID == clas))
                    .Take(3);
```

If you need first panel which have hyperlinks with a certain id, and next two panels whatever they have:

```
var thePanels = menuCell.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
                        .SkipWhile(panel => !panel.Controls.OfType<HyperLink>()
                                                 .Any(label => label.ID == clas))
                        .Take(3);
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct. This doesn't return the matched element and the 2 next elements (which may not match). It returns the first three matches.

Comment: Yes, **only the first** must match with the `ID`, the 2 next are just the 2 next within the sequence.

Comment: @bAN ...but a bit difficult ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find one panel with the specified condition, and then take it, and the two next, regardless of whether they satisfy the condition or not, you could do:

```
IEnumerable<Panel> thePanelAndTwoNext = menuCell.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
                .SkipWhile(panel => !panel.Controls.OfType<HyperLink>()
                                       .Any(label => label.ID == clas))
                .Take(3);
```